# Creating a diff array using lambda functions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I wish to create a diff array in python as follows

```
>>> a = [1,5,3,8,2,4,7,6]
>>> diff = []
>>> a = sorted(a,reverse=True)
>>> for i in xrange(len(a)-1):
        diff.append(a[i]-a[i+1])
```

But I wanted to refactor the above code. I tried to achieve it using lambda functions. But failed to get the result.

```
>>> [i for i in lambda x,y:y-x,sorted(a,reverse=True)]
```

The above code returns

```
[<function <lambda> at 0x00000000023B9C18>, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

I wished to know can the required functionality be achieved using lambda functions or any other technique?
Thanks in advance for any help!!

NOTES:

1) Array 'a' can be huge. Just for the sake of example I have taken a small array.

2) The result must be achieved in minimum time.

Comment: Do you really need/want to sort the data prior the calculation? What is the desired result with ```a``` as an input?

Comment: Diff array is to be calculated only after sorting the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,5,3,8,2,4,7,6]

j = np.diff(np.sorted(a))    # array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
print list(j)
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

k =  np.diff(a)    # array([ 4, -2,  5, -6,  2,  3, -1])
print list(k)
# [4, -2, 5, -6, 2, 3, -1]
```

Timing comparisons with one-hundred-thousand random ints - numpy is faster if the data needs to be sorted:

```
from timeit import Timer
a = [random.randint(0, 1000000) for _ in xrange(100000)]
##print a[:100]
def foo(a):
    a = sorted(a, reverse=True)
    return [a[i]-a[i+1] for i in xrange(len(a)-1)]

def bar(a):
    return np.diff(np.sort(a))

t = Timer('foo(a)', 'from __main__ import foo, bar, np, a')
print t.timeit(10)
# 0.86916993838

t = Timer('bar(a)', 'from __main__ import foo, bar, np, a')
print t.timeit(10)
# 0.28586356791
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension, as follows:

```
>>> a = sorted([1,5,3,8,2,4,7,6], reverse=True)
>>> diff = [a[i]-a[i+1] for i in xrange(len(a)-1)]
>>> diff
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

You said *or any other technique*, so I take this to be valid. However, I haven't found a working `lambda` solution yet :)

### Comparing the time of this answer with all of the below:

**Mine:**

> 1.59740447998e-05 seconds

**@Marcin's**

> 0.00110197067261 seconds

**@roippi's**

> 0.000382900238037

**@wwii's**

> 0.00154685974121

**Therefore, mine was clearly the fastest** by more than twice, followed by @roippi, followed by @Marcin, followed by @wwi.

<sup>P.S. I was completely unbiased here, my timing method was using current `time.time()` minus previous `time.time()`.</sup>

Comment: An alternative implementation for the list comprehension: `diff = v - a[i+1] for i,v in enumerate(a[:-1])]`

Comment: If you benchmark on a reasonably sized list (say, 10k elements), your function will not be the fastest.  Also you should use a real testing fixture (like `timeit`) instead of rolling your own with `time`.

Comment: I tested mine with 5,000 randomly picked elements.

Comment: With ```range(100000)```, this listcomp is still faster than converting to a numpy array then doing the diff. If the object is already an ```ndarray```, ```numpy.diff``` is about 40 times faster with 100k elements

Comment: Throw in the sort (```np.sort``` for the ndarray) and they are comparable - the listcomp is still about 10% faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could do as follows:

```
diff = [v[0] - v[1] for v in zip(sorted(a,reverse=True)[0:-1], sorted(a,reverse=True)[1:])]

#gives: diff = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Though here you use sorting twice. Not sure if this matters to you or not.

As @aj8uppal sugested its better to have a as sorted version before, so in this case you do:

```
a = sorted([1,5,3,8,2,4,7,6], reverse=True)
diff = [v[0] - v[1] for v in zip(a[0:-1], a[1:])]    
#gives: diff = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This seems like one of those cases where getting the code to be a one liner just isn't worth it. This is much less readable than a two line solution (imo), and requires sorting `a` twice.

Comment: @dano This is one possible solution. Maybe not the optimal one but does what OP wants.

Comment: The array 'a' can be huge and time complexity is a priority. This solution may fail to meet the requirements. I'll edit the problem statement accordingly.

Comment: @Marcin I suggest defining `a` as `sorted([1,5,3,8,2,4,7,6], reverse=True)` so that you don't have to write out `sorted(a,reverse=True)` twice, you can just say `a`.

Comment: @aj8uppal Thx. I cant find they way to make keep sorted in list comprehension without sorting twice. I eddied the answer, to have sorting before list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,5,3,8,2,4,7,6]
a = sorted(a,reverse=True)
```

Can't really improve these lines.  You need to transform your data by sorting it, no sense changing what you've done.

```
from itertools import izip, starmap

from operator import sub

list(starmap(sub,izip(a,a[1:])))
Out[12]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If `a` is *really* massive, you can replace the `a[1:]` slice with `islice` to save on memory overhead:

```
list(starmap(sub,izip(a,islice(a,1,None))))
```

Though if it is really that massive, you should probably be using `numpy` anyway.

```
np.diff(a) * -1
Out[24]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```